# Determine that the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+x-2}{x-1}$ is continous in $x_0=0$; $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Determine that the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+x-2}{x-1}$ is continous in $x_0=0$; $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$
>   (I only need to show continuity for $x_0=0$)

---

Let $\varepsilon>0$; ${\mid x-x_0\mid}<\delta = {\mid x-0 \mid}<\delta$ 
\begin{align} 
{\mid f(x)-f(x_0)\mid} &= {\mid\frac{x^2+x-2}{x-1}-\frac{0^2+0-2}{0-1}\mid}\\
&={\mid\frac{x^2+x-2}{x-1}-2\mid}\\
&={\mid\frac{x^2-x}{x-1}\mid}\\
&={\mid x\mid}<\delta\\
\end{align}
**Let $\delta = \varepsilon$, then if $|x-0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(0)| = |x| <\epsilon$**

---

Is there anything that should be changed?

Comment: of course $0\in\Bbb R$, then the assert $x_0\in\Bbb R$ is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct and the choice of $\delta = \epsilon$ is right.
I would make some changes to the writing to make it more readable to those who are not as familiar with the ideas as you are.

For example your last line of proof may be altered as :

Let $\epsilon = \delta$, then if $|x-0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(0)| = |x| <\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you, I'll change the last line and sorry for spamming the accept button. I always forget only one answer can be accepted...

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

It might be just a typo, but you wrote $\delta =: \varepsilon$, saying "let's define $\varepsilon$ to be equal to $\delta$." This would be a mistake, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary but fixed in the beginning of a proof and it is $\delta$ that should be defined for a particular $\varepsilon$.

Otherwise, your work looks solid. It could be simplified if you notice that $x^2+x-2 = (x+2)(x-1)$, so $f(x) = x + 2$ when $x\neq 1$ (and undefined at $x = 1$).

Comment: Thanks, I'll change that and sorry for spamming I always forget I can only accept one answer...